# Named routes with optional url $param(s) - Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've ran into a bit of a quirk with L4 (possibly symfony2?) routing for which I can't seem to find any resources online or in the wonderful Code Bright, and came up empty in IRC.

I'm trying to use optional params with a named route through a controller, but receive an error when loading the view.

#### Route:

```
Route::get('/topic/{topicID?}', array(
    'as'    => 'topicDetails',
    'uses'  => 'TopicController@showTopic'
));
```

#### Controller:

```
class TopicController extends BaseController {

    public function showTopic($topicID = null)
    {
        $data['topicID'] = $topicID;
        return View::make('topic_view', $data);
    }
}
```

#### View

```
<a href="{{ route('topicDetails') }}">XXX</a>
```

#### Error:

```
Parameter "topicID" for route "topicDetails" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

I'm assuming this isn't passing the `null` value to the `$param` but I'm not familiar enough with L4 to figure out why it isn't working, and I've exhausted all my resources.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to recreate this. Works fine for me using the exact code you posted here.

Comment: @jakeharris try this `<a href="{{ route('topicDetails',array()) }}">XXX</a>`

Comment: @JasonLewis - It was a persistent link in a nav menu, so maybe that's why you can't recreate it?

I ended up getting frustrated and running it with a get param instead.

Comment: A persistent link in the nav menu? Huh? I copied your exact code and it works fine.

Comment: @TryingTobemyself Dang, I was hoping to keep the route helper pretty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this

```
<a href="{{ route('topicDetails') }}">XXX</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="{{ route('topicDetails', null) }}">XXX</a>
```

Comment: What's the point of passing it in the controller function then?

Comment: @jakeharris `<a href="{{ route('topicDetails') }}">XXX</a>` works for me as it is, try updating your Laravel version

Comment: "null" didn't work for me, but `<a href="{{ route('my.route', '') }}">XXX</a>` did (Laravel 4.2.11)