# Redirect to named route with parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect to routes that are named and be able to use parameters in that route.

This will work but i dont want to specify the route as a specific string

```
return Redirect::to('admin/user/' . $id . '/edit')
```

I want to use the routes name, something like this:

```
return Redirect::route('user/edit')
```

But that gives me the error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

And the wrong route:

```
admin/user/%7Bid%7D/edit
```

I have specified the route and named it in my routes.php file

```
Route::get('/admin/user/{id}/edit', array(
    'as' => 'user/edit',
    'uses' => 'UserController@edit'
));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Named routes with optional url $param(s) - Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029120/named-routes-with-optional-url-params-laravel-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the Redirector wich parameter(s) you want to substitute, or it will use the 'default' you specified: in this case `{id}` (`%7B` and `%7D` are the encoded `{` and `}` respectively)

```
return Redirect::route('user/edit', array($id));
```

The method args are:

```
public RedirectResponse route(string $route, array $parameters = array(), int $status = 302, array $headers = array())
```